# why do i get Notice: Undefined offset: 65 and how to fix it

Tags: php

I keep getting this `Notice: Undefined offset: 65` on line 31 which is this line `if($k[$c]) $p = preg_replace('/\b'.base_convert($c, 10, $a).'\b/', $k[$c], $p);`. How can I fix this?

```
//function to get source html
function get_data($url) {
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    return $html;
}

//function to extract string beteen 2 delimeters
function extract_unit($string, $start, $end) {
    $pos = stripos($string, $start);
    $str = substr($string, $pos);
    $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));
    $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);
    $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);
    $unit = trim($str_three);

    return $unit;
}

//function to decode packer endcoding
function js_unpack($p,$a,$c,$k) {
  while ($c--)
    if($k[$c]) $p = preg_replace('/\b'.base_convert($c, 10, $a).'\b/', $k[$c], $p);

  return $p;
}

//url source;
$adcrunch = get_data("http://adcrun.ch/BuVE");

//gather js_packer arguments
$arg_p = extract_unit($adcrunch, 'return p}(\'', ';\',');
$arg_a = extract_unit($adcrunch, '});\',', ',');
$arg_c = extract_unit($adcrunch, ',10,', ',\'|a0x1');
$arg_k = extract_unit($adcrunch, ',\'|', '\'.split');

$p = $arg_p;
$a = $arg_a;
$c = $arg_c;
$k = explode('|', $arg_k);

echo js_unpack($p, $a, $c, $k);
```

Comment: There's no array element `$k[65]`. Either check that an array key exists before calling it, or do something else to check your array bounds after `$c--`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined offset means there is no index 65 in the array $k

You could "avoid" the warning by doing either:

```php
if(isset($k[c]))
```

or

```php
if(array_key_exists($c, $k))
```

Shai.

Comment: Thanks but can I ask you if this code (http://pastebin.com/DrCc3ncq) matches the js_unpack function? because When I add `if(array_key_exists($c, $k))` it returns a blank page.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP versions of the packer, but you can try this : http://drupal.org/files/issues/js-packer.inc_.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead

```
if(isset($k[$c]) && $k[$c])
```

`$c` is probaly 65, and `$k[65]` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Or you use

```
if(array_key_exists($c,$k)) ...
```